# A word for organized deconstruction

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for words that convey the following meaning.

Deconstructing a system in a detailed and organized manner (it's not a destruction) in order to understand its internals (how it works) and then being able to reconstruct it.

Comment: Well, there's "disassembly".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the composition of what you're deconstructing you might consider either:

[Dissection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dissection)

> the action of cutting something open, especially a dead body or plant, in order to study its structure

or [breakdown](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/breakdown)

> a division of something into smaller parts:

Dissection is usually used in an organic context, while breakdown might apply more to an engineering system or component.

Answer (score 1):

Dissection and breakdown are good choices. I thought of dismantle.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to suggest *decomposition*. This suggests a deconstruction faithful to the means by which the thing is constructed, or composed.

Answer (score 0):

What’s wrong with **deconstruction?**

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction

This is a standard term.

There’s also *reverse engineer*.